# Normalizing edit distance on strings

Tags: clustering, text-mining, distance, distance-functions

I am going to run a clustering algorithm on strings (sequences of characters). I would like to use the edit distance, but it seems to be misleading as I perceive `Anna` to be closer to `Anne` than `A` to `B`. Both have edit distance 2.

My idea would be to normalize the edit distance by sum of lengths of both strings. In that case, we would have $2/8$ for `Anna` to `Anne`; and for `A` to `B` we would have $2/2$.

On the other hand `A` to `B` seems to be closer `Adam` to `Paris`. Is there any class of distance metrics that could manage the trade-off. Namely

```
d('Anna','Anne') < d('A','B') <= d('Adam','Paris')
```

Comment: Edit distance is not one: there are versions of it, including versions of "the denominator" (normalizing) level. They use sum length, mean length, geometric mean, max, and what not. Just be free to contemplate alternatives, including your own, and to select what will suit most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly common "normalized" Levenshtein version that works just like that exists.

I don't know any reference. Dividing by the length is probably so obvious that nobody considers this worth publishing. It's simply referred to as "normalized Levenshtein distance".

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Seems like it exists even explicitly at http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4160958/ Unfortunately, I do not have the access to that paper.

Comment: Just a question: do you mean normalizing by length of one of strings or both of them?

Comment: Whichever makes more sense for your *data*.

Comment: Note the abstract of that paper begins with:
"Although **a number of normalized edit distances presented so far** may offer good performance in some applications, none of them can be regarded as a genuine metric..." - I don't know if you need a metric, or just something that works.